# Simplificar SP de múltiples consultas SQLServer

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estimad@s, buenas tardes, quisiera consultarles sobre: ¿Cómo puedo evitar repetir la misma consulta para distintas consultas? Lo que requiero hacer es un SP que se encargue de eliminar n cantidad de cuotas impagas, pero para ello primero debo realizar un INSERT a dos tablas que funcionan como historial. La primera recibe los siguientes datos:

```
INSERT INTO CVE(Titulo, usuario, mail)
(SELECT TITULO, 'automatico', 0
FROM C
WHERE TITULO IN (SELECT ANTITSOL FROM S WHERE IDC IN ('00086', '00097') AND ANTITSOL IS NOT NULL) AND FECGRABAC IS NULL 
GROUP BY TITULO)
```

Esto genera un id en CVE único (CVE_Id). Ahora, a ese id CVE único lo debo usar para insertar datos en otra tabla histórica:

```
INSERT INTO CVD(CVE_Id, cuota, importe, CueId)
SELECT CVE_Id, C.CUOIMPRESA, C.IMPCOMPROB, C.CODIGO
FROM CVE CVE, C C
WHERE CVE.Titulo = C.TITULO AND CAST(CVE.Solicitado AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Ahora, debo eliminar todos los datos de la tabla C que se hayan insertado en la tabla CVE:

```
DELETE FROM C
WHERE CODIGO IN (SELECT CODIGO FROM C WHERE TITULO IN (SELECT ANTITSOL FROM Solicitud   WHERE IDC IN ('00086', '00097') AND FECGRABAC IS NULL))
```

Una vez eliminado, debo actualizar otra tabla:

```
UPDATE S
SET ACULCUOIMPSOL = ISNULL(COUNT(*), 0),
    EstaVerif = NULL
WHERE ANTITSOL IN (SELECT TITULO FROM C WHERE TITULO IN (SELECT ANTITSOL FROM S WHERE IDC IN ('00086', '00097') AND ANTITSOL IS NOT NULL) AND FECGRABAC IS NULL GROUP BY TITULO)
```

Lo que quiero saber es si puedo simplificar este proceso y en tal caso, ¿Cómo debo hacerlo?

Comment: porque?? que problema tiene ese SP??? y por simplificar, te referirias a que??? }

Comment: Pues, problemas no tiene, por simplificar me refiero a si puedo hacerlo más corto.  Capaz así como está, está bien y no necesita modificaciones pero me surgió la duda de si podría simplificar pasos y la repetición de la consulta: `(SELECT ANTITSOL FROM Solicitud   WHERE IDC IN ('00086', '00097') AND FECGRABAC IS NULL))` @gbianchi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puesto que no hay muchos datos acerca de que es lo importante, lo único que se me ocurre es eliminar la consulta que se repite constantemente para almacenarla en una tabla temporal que puedas usar múltiples veces.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  
        TITULO,  
        CODIGO
INTO #TituloCodigo
FROM C
WHERE TITULO IN (SELECT ANTITSOL 
                FROM S 
                WHERE IDC IN ('00086', '00097') 
                AND ANTITSOL IS NOT NULL) 
AND FECGRABAC IS NULL ;

INSERT INTO CVE(Titulo, usuario, mail)
SELECT DISTINCT 
        TITULO, 
        'automatico', 
        0
FROM #TituloCodigo;

INSERT INTO CVD(CVE_Id, cuota, importe, CueId)
SELECT  CVE_Id, 
        C.CUOIMPRESA, 
        C.IMPCOMPROB, 
        C.CODIGO
FROM CVE CVE
JOIN C   C   ON CVE.Titulo = C.TITULO 
WHERE CAST(CVE.Solicitado AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE);

DELETE FROM C
WHERE CODIGO IN (SELECT CODIGO FROM #TituloCodigo); -- El operador IN ignora los duplicados

UPDATE S
SET ACULCUOIMPSOL = ISNULL(COUNT(*), 0),
    EstaVerif = NULL
WHERE ANTITSOL IN (SELECT TITULO FROM #TituloCodigo); -- El operador IN ignora los duplicados
```

Comment: Fantástico, muchas gracias. Te consulto, ¿Hay alguna diferencia relevante para usar `Join` o es que es solo el sinónimo de `Inner Join`?

Comment: `INNER` y `OUTER` son palabras opcionales para describir el tipo de `JOIN`. Cuando solo aparece `JOIN`, se intuye que es `INNER`. Cuando aparece `LEFT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN` o `FULL JOIN` se asume que es `OUTER`. Existe un caso avanzado en el que la palabra no es opcional, pero por ahora no viene al caso.